# reference implementation for design patterns

Tags: java, design-patterns, jakarta-ee

just like camel provides a reference implementation for the enterprise integration patterns, what would you consider the reference implementation for the GoF design patterns?

Comment: Are you looking for a "best practice" code? What about the code from the GoF book?

Comment: They are all straight forward, so I don't see the need for an implementation.  And they must be adapted to your particular problem, so a reference implementation would not be useful since you would need to rewrite everything anyway.

Answer (score 5):

A  [Reference Implementation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_implementation) is a model implementation that all others are supposed to measure against.

E.g. `JAX-WS` is Java's build in reference implementation of web services standard.

And SUN's JDK is SUNs reference implementation of the Java Language Specification.

A Design Pattern is a best (reusuable) solution to a recurring software engineering problem.
As per this definition there can be no reference implementation of design patterns since they are are only a well known and proven description/template on how to fix a specific problem

Answer (score 2):

There can be no such thing and your question has no meaning

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the answer of @Alex and @user384706 :

There are two hints in the book itself which make is clear that no meaningful reference implementation is possible:

- Chapter 1.7: *How to Select a Design Pattern* and chapter 1.8 *How to Use a Design Pattern*
  talk about redsign, adaption, changing naming conventions etc.
- Each pattern chapter has an *Implementation* section which discusses several variations depending on some desired or to be avoided side effects. These variations often have competing goals. Therefore no meaningful reference implementation can cover all those aspects.

I used the term *meaningful reference implementation*. This term should make it clear that there may be libraries which claim to implement the GoF patterns in a reusable way. Given the points above and from the other answers I have not seen any such library which did not have severe implementation deficiencies at the first sight.